# Object inside parentheses

Tags: java

I have just started learning java and couldn't find this anywhere, sorry for that.
But here it goes,

As the homework, I'm required to use calling method

*kasvata(laskurini, 2);*

instead of what I have right now:

Class 1:

```
    Laskuri laskurini = new Laskuri();
    laskurini.kasvata(2);
    System.out.println(laskurini.lukema());//tulostuu 2
    laskurini.kasvata(-5);
    System.out.println(laskurini.lukema());//tulostuu 2
```

So instead of putting it like *public void kasvata(int more)*, how to use the method as I described in the class

Class 2:

```
public class Laskuri { 

private int more;
private int number;

public Laskuri(){
this.number = 0;
}

public void kasvata(int more){
    this.more = more;
    number = number + more;  
}

public int lukema(){
    return number;
}
}
```

Thanks in advance, and sorry I'm my English is not too good.

EDIT: SO, I'm supposed to have 2 classes (worth mentioning now..)

Comment: Shouldn't it print `-3` on the second call?

Comment: So you need a static function called `kasvata` that takes a `Laskuri` and an `int`?

Comment: it should print -3 on second call, and yes, i need that sorta function for it

Comment: So, make a static method inside `Laskuri` that takes 2 parameters, `Laskuri` and `int`, then modify the `Laskuri` that was passed as a parameter?

Comment: I have to have 2 classes, one where I call for the parameters, and the second one which has all the rest, classes are marked more clearly now

Comment: Then put the static method in the second class. It doesn't make a difference. It'll be like the first code you have, except you'll be using the `laskuri` parameter that's passed in instead of creating a `new Laskuri()`.

Answer (score -1):

```
public class Laskuri {
private static int number = 0;

public static void kasvata(Laskuri la, int more) {
    number = number + more;
}

public int lukema() {
    return number;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Laskuri laskurini = new Laskuri();

    kasvata(laskurini, 2);
    System.out.println(laskurini.lukema());
    kasvata(laskurini, -5);
    System.out.println(laskurini.lukema());
}
}
```

Comment: this almost solves the problem, the thing is that I'm supposed to have 2 classes, where one is that Laskuri class and other one has     kasvata(laskurini, 2);
    System.out.println(laskurini.lukema());
    kasvata(laskurini, -5);
    System.out.println(laskurini.lukema()); on it